# Copying data from the rows of different tables to one line to another

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have such a situation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The table-third would like to get the value of fcd for "C20 / 25" and fyk for B400C.

The following method works but not what I want:

```
INSERT INTO Column(fck) 
    SELECT fck 
    FROM StrengthClassesForConcrete 
    WHERE nameClass = "C20/25";

INSERT INTO Column(fyk) 
    SELECT fyk 
    FROM StrengthClassesForSteel 
    WHERE nameClass = "B400C"
```

[image]

I wish they added to one line, and that was always only one row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
 INSERT INTO Column(fck,fyk) 
     SELECT StrengthClassesForConcrete.fck, StrengthClassesForSteel.fyk 
     FROM   StrengthClassesForConcrete, StrengthClassesForSteel 
     WHERE  StrengthClassesForConcrete.nameClass = "C20/25" 
     AND    StrengthClassesForSteel.nameClass = "B400C"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what SQL-Implementation you are using. But you can do a join like this (for standard SQL):

```
INSERT INTO <table> (fck,fyk) SELECT StrengthClassesForConcrete.fck, StrengthClassesForSteel.fyk FROM StrengthClassesForConcrete, StrengthClassesForSteel WHERE StrengthClassesForConcrete.nameClass = "C20/25" AND StrengthClassesForSteel.nameClass = "B400C"
```

or shorter with aliases:

```
insert into <table> (fck,fyk) SELECT a.fck, b.fyk FROM StrengthClassesForConcrete a, StrengthClassesForSteel b WHERE a.nameClass = "C20/25" AND b.nameClass = "B400C"
```

`<table>` must be replaced with the name of your desired table/view

Answer (score 0):

You need to first join both the tables using cross join and then it will become one table and from that table you will select a row and insert it into the table.